# How to make broadcast receiver to listen event for particular app in android?

Tags: android

I am developing an app which contain list of app, when user click of particular app from list shown to him he will directed to website from which he can download that app to listen app is successfully download I add a broadcast receiver in android menifest.xml.The problem is that broadcast receiver listen if any app downloaded in system as well as from my app also.what I want broadcast receiver should listen only events from app only when my app is open as well as closed.

here is my java code:-

```
public class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // Check if the application is install or uninstall and display the message accordingly
    if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED")) {
        // Application Install
        Log.e("Package Added:-", intent.getData().toString());

    } else if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED")) {

        Log.e("Package Removed:-", intent.getData().toString());
    } else if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED")) {
        Log.e("Package Replaced:-", intent.getData().toString());
    }


}
```

}

here is my xml code:-

```
<receiver android:name=".Receiver">
        <intent-filter android:priority="100">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_INSTALL"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED"/>
            <data android:scheme="package"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

kinldy help me I am trying from a week plsss.

Comment: You can't restrict the broadcasts to your Receiver like that. You'll just have to check the package in the `onReceive()` method, and determine if you want to do anything there.

Comment: code to check package

Comment: is there any way to find url from package name like :https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.example.launcher&hl=en"

Answer (score 2):

There is no way for you to know whether the package is installed by your app just with the information in the `Intent` received by your `BroadcastReceiver`. Technically, your app isn't installing anything, the system does that (third party apps do not have the privilege to install other apps).

You will have to check the package name from the `Intent` data and compare it to apps the user downloaded with your app. That's the best you can do.

Comment: how can I do that any reference pls

Comment: not to check particular package if two or three app are downlaoded from my app

Comment: @Nitin You should store that information when the user selects an app inside of your app.